# Trying to make div boxes expand

Tags: html, css, hover, expand, netflix

Currently im trying to create a nextflix clone. my issue is that when i hover over a movie box, it expands but also pushes the other movie boxes down and only expands in one direction. not sure how to fix this. thanks in advance.

html

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover{  
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/shauneb/pen/Epoxrx
//example of the issue im facing

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is what you want but, you can use css to modify the size of a block without it moving its siblings by using transform: scale(2); in the hover css.

Scale resizes the element to the viewer, but the "volume" of the element stays the same, so it doesn't move the other div

Modification of your example using scale:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.box{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
/*   position: absolute; */
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover{
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: green"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: violet"></div>
  <div class="box"  style="background-color: red"></div>
</div>
```

*note: I also added a position: relative to the boxes and a z-index to make sure that the one you are hover will be always on the top of the other elements.*

https://codepen.io/ancode/pen/pZpJRN

Answer (score 2):

You have to just add vertical-align:top css in .box class then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to push it just in one direction (vertically), you just need to change height of the element not width, and also using `display: inline-block` causes pushing other elements too.

so your styles should be:

```
.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover{
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style for .box

```
.box{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    transition: .5s;
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 10px;
}
```

If you use this hover effect you will get following output:

```
.box:hover{  
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

[image]

If you use this hover effect you will get following output:

```
.box:hover{  
   transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced your transition with `transform: scale(2);` 
and aligned the box in middle using `vertical-align:middle;`

Hope this might be useful.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
/*   position: absolute; */
  display: inline-block;
  transition:transform .5s ease;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box:hover{
  
 transform: scale(2); 
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Movie 1</div>
  <div class="box">Movie 2</div>
  <div class="box">Movie 3</div>
  <div class="box">Movie 4</div>
</div>
```